# hiding implementation details through the usage of protected virtual

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, oop

A coworker introduced me to the concept of hiding implementation details through allowing the derived class to override the private field initializations.

For example I have a base class:

```
public class Animal
{
   private Dog dog;
   private Cat cat;
   private Mouse mouse;

   protected virtual void Init()
   {
      dog = new Dog();
      cat = new Cat();
      mouse = new Mouse();
   }

   public void DoStuff() {}

}
```

This allows me to override the initialization within a derived class of the base class privates:

```
public class Cookie : Animal
{
   protected override void init()
   {
      //do whatever i want here
   }
}
```

1. Does this type of implementation-detail-hiding have a name?
2. Would I ever call Init() from Animal or does this pattern insist on Init() because called from a derived class?

**What am I trying to achieve?**

I have a class (animal in the example above) that has about 20 private objects that need to be initialized, and I want to be able to define my own way of initializing them specifically when doing unit testing.

Comment: Your second question is not clear, can you please rephrase and explain what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: @SirajMansour updated to answer your question

Comment: Hmm... I think we call them `virtual methods`?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx - by the way, you should look at SRP, where they turn the whole paradigm on its ears.

Comment: when you have a class library of SRP classes and you need to use them, you end up with a master class where you need to instantiate all of your SRPs, and that is why i have 20 of them

Answer (score 2):

1) This is simply overriding, i am not aware that it is more than that. But you cannot access private fields in a subclass, they have to be protected as well so you can access them in your subclass.

2) Your question is not clear, but i am guessing you are asking how you can call the method of the base class from within the override. all you need to do is

```
public class Cookie : Animal
{
   protected override void init()
   {
      //do whatever you want here
      base.init(); //This line will call the init() function in Animal. 
      //do whatever you want here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is simply called [`override`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx).

> An override method provides a new implementation of a member that is
>   inherited from a base class.

You can invoke the `base class`' `overriden method` `Init()` from the `derived class` by using `base.Init();`.